# What does "right round toward" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

Can anybody help me to describe the meaning of "right round toward", especially in the **bold sentence** of the context below.

Context:

*Within two years, Deng was the most powerful man in China. Deng's moment had come, and what a moment! **He took China right round towards roaring full-throttle capitalism.***

More context if needed:

*... Under Deng, China's repressive state continued, but he began welding together the two big ideas that had divided the world in the 20th century. For him, capitalism in a communist country wasn't a contradiction, it was a pragmatic solution. Since Deng's reforms were introduced, China's economy has been growing at an average of nearly 10% a year every year. It's on track to become the world's biggest economy by 2016. ...*

Source: History of the world by Andrew Marr - episode 8

Answer (score 2):

China must have been going in the direction of socialism when Deng came on the scene.

> *adverb*: **[right](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/right)** ODO (scroll down to "adverb")
>      1. to the furthest or most complete extent or degree (used for emphasis).
>      *the car spun right off the track*
>      synonyms: completely, fully, totally, absolutely, utterly, thoroughly, quite
>   
>   *adverb* **[round](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/round)** ODO (scroll down to "adverb")
>   chiefly British
>      2 So as to rotate and face in the opposite direction:
>      *he swung round to face her*

Deng (Xiaoping) veered the country 180°, in the **totally opposite** direction, of capitalism. Note "contradiction" in the commentary: *For him, capitalism in a communist country wasn't a contradiction*.

HTH.